# How to solve boolean[]/Boolean[] method function mismatch?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to send `public static boolean key[] = new boolean[68836];` to the method in another class. But keep getting the following error:

```
error: method tick in class Game cannot be applied to given types;
  game.tick(key);
   required: Boolean[]
   found: boolean[]
   reason: actual argument boolean[] cannot be converted to Boolean[] by method 
invocation conversion
```

**Ah, I saw what I did wrong! But now I also learned something that I did not know before. All thanks to Eran.**

Comment: Make an array of `Boolean` instead?

Comment: Consider improving your title. It isn't very helpful as it doesn't refer to the problem in any way.

Comment: If you're not sure of the difference between Boolean and boolean, do some research on wrapper classes for primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A boolean array cannot be converted to a Boolean array. boolean is primitive, Boolean is a sub-class of Object.

You should pass a `Boolean[]` to your method, since that's what it expects.

Comment: The funny thing is that it works in Eclipse but not in Netbeans.

Comment: @MegaMeanboy - Not the same code.  Likely either the parm value or the method definition is different in one vs the other.

Comment: Ah, I saw what I did wrong! But now I also learned something that I did not know before. All thanks to Eran.